# TinkerPop: Multi-Level search to multiple - vertex types

Tags: python, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

**Sample Graph**: [Tinker Modern](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/images/tinkerpop-modern.png)

**Query**: Find all direct friends (`person` Vertex) of Marko and (union) all `software` in second hop.

---

**Failed attempts:**

> Generic Query for first level people:

```
g.V(1).hasLabel("person").repeat(both()).times(1).emit(hasLabel("person")).hasLabel("person").values("name")
```

> Generic Query for second level/hop software:

```
g.V(1).hasLabel("person").repeat(both()).times(2).emit(hasLabel("software")).hasLabel("software").values("name")
```

> Attempt to merge above two queries:

```
g.V(1).hasLabel("person").repeat(both()).times(1).emit(hasLabel("person")).hasLabel("person").repeat(both()).times(2).emit(hasLabel("software")).hasLabel("software").values("name")
```

I didn't really understand how union works, because its not merging data.

```
g.V(1).union().V(2)
g.V(1).union(V(2))
```

Best I got till now is, but I want some ability to do like (marko connected to person AND/OR marko connected to software):

```
gremlin> g.V(1).store('x').V(2).store('y').cap('x', 'y')
==>[x:[v[1]],y:[v[2]]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This for first level:

```
gremlin> g.V(1).hasLabel("person").as("from", "to1", "to2")
            .repeat(both()).times(1).emit(hasLabel("person")).hasLabel("person").as("to1")
            .select("from")
            .repeat(both()).times(1).emit(hasLabel("software")).hasLabel("software").as("to2")
            .project("from", "person", "software")
            .by(select("from").by("name"))
            .by(select("to1").by("name"))
            .by(select("to2").by("name"))
```

Result:

```
==>[from:marko,person:vadas,software:lop]
==>[from:marko,person:josh,software:lop]
```

For multilevel increse the value of `times`